# SQL query involving data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I am really new to SQL & it would be really helpful if somebody can help with one simple query that I am struggling to write.

**list**
(
      plid,
      fid
)

**files**
(
      fid,
      filename
)

I want to get the fid & filename from the above tables where plid=3. The steps would be 
1) Get the fid values from table "list" where plid=x 
2) Get the filename from "files" for all the matched fid in table "list".

Comment: You should use `JOIN` clause. It is easy. Try by yourself.

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried so far, and where it went wrong? It encourages others to help if you show your own efforts and where exactly you are stuck/which bits you don't understand.

Comment: Work through a good tutorial liek this one: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I will definitely take a look at this today. Time was short & I needed an answer quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly where you need a `JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT list.fid, files.filename FROM list INNER JOIN files ON files.fid = list.fid WHERE files.plid = 3
```

Comment: Yeah, it is very useful for his understandings.

Comment: Write a better answer. Seriously, joins are so fundamental, a very quick search on google or clicking on one of the related questions on the side will tell him all he needs to know. I just lead him in the right direction.

Comment: You didn't understand my sarcasm. I mean, he have to write query by himself, without your direct answer. And where is your _lead him_? :)

Comment: Thanks Ke Vin. It worked. Regarding the query that I had done so far, **SELECT list.fid, files.filename FROM list INNER JOIN files ON plid=3** and I was unsure about how to put the list.fid=files.fid.